# How big $|\operatorname{Aut}(M)|$ can be, given $|\partial\operatorname{Aut}(M)|$?

Tags: lo.logic, gn.general-topology, topological-groups, automorphism-groups

My apologies: There were a couple of typos in the original question. Hope I got them all.

Let $\kappa$ be an uncountable cardinal of cofinality $\omega$ and $M$ a model of size $\kappa$. We equip $\kappa^\kappa$ with the product topology and let $\operatorname{Aut}(M)\subset \kappa^\kappa$ denote the topological group of automorphisms of $M$. The closure of $\operatorname{Aut}(M)$ under the product topology is denoted by $\overline{\operatorname{Aut}(M)}$ and $\partial \operatorname{Aut}(M)=\overline{\operatorname{Aut}(M)}\setminus\operatorname{Aut}(M)$ denotes the boundary of $\operatorname{Aut}(M)$.

My question is: If we know that (EDIT)$|\partial\operatorname{Aut}(M)|\ge\kappa^+$(EDIT), can we say anything about the cardinality of $\operatorname{Aut}(M)$, other than (EDIT)$|\operatorname{Aut}(M)|\le|\partial\operatorname{Aut}(M)|$(EDIT)?

Side note: If $f$ is in $\partial\operatorname{Aut}(M)$, then $f$ is 1-1, not onto, and for every formula $\phi$ and every finite $\vec{a}$, $M\models\phi[\vec{a}]$ iff $M\models\phi[f(\vec{a})]$. I.e. $f$ is an elementary embedding.

Comment: For the product topology on $\kappa^\kappa$, you place the discrete topology on each factor? 

Comment: Well, we can say that $|Aut(M)| \le \kappa^+$ because, choosing $f \in \partial Aut(M)$, the map $g \mapsto f \circ g$ is an injection $Aut(M) \to \partial Aut(M)$.

So if $|Aut(M)| \ge \kappa^+$ (this isn't immediately apparent to me) then $|Aut(M)| = \kappa^+$.

Comment: I was assuming that you meant the product of the discrete topologies on $\kappa$, by the way.

Comment: At both Joel and Trevor: Yes, the topology on $\kappa$ is the discrete topology.

Comment: @ Trevor: Your argument establishes $|Aut(M)|\le|\partial Aut(M)|$. My apologies there are a couple of typos in the question. It seems it has been a long day!

Comment: So to be clear, $\partial$ here is not the usual $\partial$ from point-set topology?  Or does it coincide for some reason?  It doesn't seem like it should.

Comment: @Harry: I think you are right. I just looked the definition up. The boundary of $A$ in point-set topology is the difference between the closure of $A$ and the interior of $A$, not the difference between the closure of $A$ and $A$ itself, as we have it here. 

Answer (score 1):

By Trevor's comment, $\DeclareMathOperator{\Aut}{Aut}|\Aut(M)|\leq|\partial \Aut(M)|$.
From purely topological considerations we get this:

Let $\lambda=\Aut(M)$.
The closure of $\Aut(M)$ cannot have more than $2^{2^\lambda}$ elements.
If $\kappa^+\leq|\partial \Aut(M)|$, then we must have $2^{2^\lambda}\geq\kappa^+$.
So in particular, if GCH or something similar holds below $\kappa$, we have $|\Aut(M)|\geq\kappa$.

Comment: Stefan, this is a nice observation making use of the fact that $\kappa$ is a limit cardinal. My original motivation stemmed from the fact that for $\kappa$ countable, the mere existence of one element in $\partial Aut(M)$ implies the existence of $2^\omega$ many automorphisms. This follows from a theorem of Su Gao in "On automorphism groups of countable structures", J. Symb. Log. 63, No.3, 891-896 (1998). 
                              

Answer (score 0):

I was able to prove the following for $\kappa$ of cofinality $\omega$:

Assume $M$ is a model of size $\kappa$, $cf(\kappa)=\omega$ and for all $\alpha<\beta<\kappa^+$, there exist functions $j_{\beta,\alpha}$ in $\DeclareMathOperator{\Aut}{Aut}\overline{\Aut(M)}^{T}\setminus \Aut(M)$, such that for $\alpha<\beta<\gamma<\kappa^+$,

$$(*) j_{\gamma,\beta}\circ j_{\beta,\alpha}=j_{\gamma,\alpha},$$
where $\overline{\Aut(M)}^{T}$ is the closure of $\Aut(M)$ under the product topology in $\kappa^\kappa$.

Then there are at least $\kappa^\omega$ automorphisms of $M$.
The proof is using Infinitary Logic and the assumption that $cf(\kappa)=\omega$ is fundamental.

I do not know of any way to get the above result directly.

(link to arXiv: [arXiv:1211.7145](https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.7145)).